# what could I be doing wrong in running a flask app using python

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal

I’m learning flask app development and recently got hinged on a problem where on setting all necessary conditions in a venv

```
set FLASK_APP=<folder containing flask app> or
set FLASK_APP=<flask app file>

set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

for an app run I get no output at all instead the terminal just reads it and requests for another command. [Here are the terminal outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftmuA.jpg)

Below is my folder structure:
[flask folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVNe2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

cd in your `flask_setup_example` dir then run:

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```